# How to add a duplicate library to Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven

One of my projects is a spin-off of another, and they utilize slightly different 'common' libraries.
I want to run them simultaneously, but I can't import the spin-off 'common' library in Maven as the original library is already there.
How to solve this collision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might have to use the [Maven Shade](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) plugin.  It effectively lets you use both libraries at the same time, but one (or both) will get a modified package path.  This means you'll have to change the references to one (or both) of them.